# MOBILE ONLY | Anchor does not work when windows.location is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code:

```
// index.html
<a id="my_id" data-target="http://www.example.com" href="index.html" target="_blank">Press me</a>

// script.js
$('#my_id').on('click', function(){            
    window.location = $('#my_id').attr("data-target");
});
```

What I want to do in fact is that when I press on this anchor, I want to:

1. Open another tab with the same page (via href)
2. The first tab should redirect to http://www.example.com (via window.location)

The code above works only on desktop, when I give it a try on a mobile it does not work like this. On the mobile my current page redirects to http://www.example.com without opening the new tab with the current page.

Any ideea why this happens and how can I fix this ?